# Substring with Multiple Arguments

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, substring

I have a dropdownlist that has the value of two columns in it... One column is a number ranging from 5 characters long to 8 characters long then a space then the '|' character and another space, followed by a Description for the set of numbers.

An example:

```
12345678 | Description of Product
```

In order to pull the items for the dropdownlist into my database I need a to utilize a substring to pull the sequence of numbers out only.

Is it possible to write a substring to pull multiple character lengths? (Sometimes it may be 6 numbers, sometimes 5 numbers, sometimes 8, it would depend on what the user selected from the dropdownlist.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression for this.

Assuming the number is at the start of the string, you can use the following:

```
^[0-9]+
```

Usage:

```
var theNumbers = RegEx.Match(myDropdownValue, "^[0-9]+").Value;
```

You could also use `string.Split` to get the parts separated by `|` if you know the first part is what you need and will always be numeric:

```
var theNumbers = myDropdownValue.Split("| ".ToCharArray(), 
                                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
```

---

Either of these approaches will result in a *string*. You can use `int.Parse` on the result in order to get an integer from it.

Comment: How would I tie that into my substring? it looks like this: value.substring( ) would it be value.substring^[0-9]+??

Comment: @developthestars - You don't. I am suggesting that you use a regular expression instead of substring.

Comment: O I see new to .NET and I'm not entirely familiar with Regular expressions yet. Thanks@

Comment: @developthestars - Given you another option.

Comment: So If I wanted to get the description part it should be var theNumbers = myDropDownValue.Splist(" |".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];   ?

Comment: @developthestars - No, you would replace the `0` with a `1`. The result of `Split` is a string array.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it

```
 string str = "12345678 | Description of Product";
 int delimiter;
 delimiter = str.IndexOf("|") - 1;

 string ID =str.substring(0, delimiter);

 string desc = str.substring(delimiter + 1, str.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using substring, you should use Split function.

```
var words = phrase.Split(new string[] {" | "},
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var number = word[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regex to pull out the first match of a sequence of numbers of any length. The regex will look something like "^\d+" - starts with any number of decimal digits.